# How can I apply a rewrite to only one term?

Tags: theorem-proving, lean

In Lean I occasionally want to apply a `rw` tactic to exactly one of multiple identical terms.  For example I have the goal

```
⊢ 0 = 0
```

and I want to `rw` it to

```
⊢ a * 0 = 0
```

I also have

```
mul_zero (a : mynat) :
  a * 0 = 0
```

Now I should be able to just rewrite the `0` to `a * 0`.  However trying

```
rw ← zero_mul a,
```

gives me

```
⊢ a * 0 = a * 0
```

Which is not what I want!

Is there a reason lean does this and is there some way to apply a rewrite to only one term?

Answer (score 7):

`rw` rewrites all identical terms simultaneously.
There is a different tactic [nth_rewrite](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#nth_rewrite%20/%20nth_rewrite_lhs%20/%20nth_rewrite_rhs) which only rewrites a specific occurrence of a term. You need mathlib for `nth_rewrite`, and I'm not sure if it is available in the Natural Number Game.

```
import tactic
example : 0 = 0 :=
begin
  nth_rewrite 0 [← nat.mul_zero 2],
  -- ⊢ 2 * 0 = 0
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the conv tactics for this

```
lemma a : 0 = 0 :=
begin
  conv {
    to_lhs, 
    rw ← nat.mul_zero 2,
  },
end
```

see: https://leanprover-community.github.io/extras/conv.html